# Using SQLLite to deleting 50 records from 60K data takes more time(17560 ms)

Tags: c#, sqlite

Actual data count is 60K, in that I am Deleting only 50 records using below query

```
Delete from Analysis where AnalysisKey in (34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67, 68,69,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73)
```

How to make faster to delete those records?

Comment: Sounds like you need a better index on your table. Do you have an index?

Comment: Is it always that ordered? Then maybe you can use `AnalysisKey BETWEEN 34 AND 73` or at least `AnalysisKey >= 34 AND AnalysisKey <= 73`. Also Indices!

Comment: I suspect that the performance lag is not in the minor difference between the IN(...) and BETWEEN, but in a full table scan looking for AnalysisKey matches. Is AnalysisKey indexed? Is it defined as the primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use sqlite before but can't you use [between](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#between)?

```
Delete from Analysis where AnalysisKey between 34 and 73
```

Comment: Yes, SQLite has the `BETWEEN` operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a large amount of rows without commiting your transaction in between almost all databases will perform slowly.

On the other hand selecting the rows to delete could be an issue. Check your query performance with an appropriate tool and ensure you have proper indexes.